# preg match in php grabs the whole string?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to match a string from a large string.

example

"quick brown fox is here but quick brown fox always over there too"

```
 preg_match('(quick brown fox(.+?)too)',$txt,$match)
```

the problem is it grabs the whole sentence rather than "quick brown fox always over there too"

How do I grab only the second part?..this happens when there are similar strings are together in one line or so...

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 capturing groups here. Your `$match` array will contain..

```
[0] => quick brown fox is here but quick brown fox always over there too
[1] => quick brown fox is here but quick brown fox always over there too
[2] => is here but quick brown fox always over there
```

Also, you're missing the two forward slashes in your regex.

Comment: Actually, the surrounding `()` act as delimiters, they're not a capturing group.

Comment: @F.Müller No, `+?` is the *non-greedy* version of `+`.

Comment: I don't think you can use `()`, but in theory you could use `((` or `))` - but as those are reserved, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Non-greedyness is applied only at the *end* of the pattern (actually, it means, that if prce finds a match, doesn't look for a larger match, just returns), so:

"quick brown fox is here too, and always over there too"

```
preg_match('(quick brown fox(.+?)too)', $txt, $match)
```

would match only "quick brown fox is here too" - but nothing, what you're looking for.

Maybe you could reverse your $txt with `strrev()` & write a reversed pattern, than reverse your matches too, but it will only solve this specific problem.

Comment: That code returns the whole sentence rather last matching part ..I am trying for the exact second part..Ignoring the first match somehow